# How to save character data from table/dataframe without double quotes as csv or txt file in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, quotes

When a file containing a table or dataframe with character values has been created in R using `write.table()` or `write.csv()`, but is opened on a text editor, the values are all in double quotes in the text editor, for example

```
"MM","M786"
"MM","M797"
"MM","M801"
```

Is there a way  to save the table or dataframe in R so that the double quotes do not show when opening the file with a text editor? So it shoud be

```
MM,M786 
MM,M797  
MM,M801
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `quote = FALSE` -

```
write.csv(df, 'out.csv', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
write.table(df, 'out.txt', quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `fwrite`

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(df, 'out.csv')
fwrite(df, 'out.txt')
```